# Is it a bad practice to refresh a page with ajax?

Tags: javascript

I have a dashboard and I need to make it dynamic so the user have up to date data.

My first "lazy" idea was to call the same page with ajax and then only update some node element every 5 seconds. Here is an example :

```
const interval = setInterval(function() {
   updateData();
 }, 5000);

function updateData(){
    let xmlhttp;
    xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if (xmlhttp.readyState === 4 && xmlhttp.status === 200){
            let parser = new DOMParser();
            let responseHtml = parser.parseFromString(xmlhttp.responseText, 'text/html');

            // Find div in the response
            let responseData = responseHtml.querySelector(".card-highlight .card-body");
            // Find the same div in the current page and get HTML data
            let currentData = document.querySelector(".card-highlight .card-body").innerHTML;
            
            // Check if the content is not the same
            if (responseData && currentData !== responseData.innerHTML) {
                // Update div with new data
                document.querySelector(".card-highlight .card-body").innerHTML = data.innerHTML
            }
        }
    }
    xmlhttp.open("GET", window.location.href, true);
    xmlhttp.send();
}
```

This is a local dashboard so there is no delay with an external server. I'm doing a page refresh. It's great for my case since I don't need extra code and I can do it on multiple page without changing my backend.

Everybody use a specific endpoint to return prepared data. But, is it necessary when we only need a **refresh** ?

It's simple and it's working for me but, is it a bad practice or a bad idea ?

- Ressource usage ?
- Security ?

Comment: If you need a complete page refresh, ajax would seem like the wrong job.  If you only want to update fragments of the page, ajax is ideal.  However, the ideal way for grabbing those fragments would be from an endpoint that returns just those fragments, or the data needed to update them.  Returning an entire page, to then grab just parts of them with ajax, is sorta smelly.

Comment: Angular framework that will fetch JSON data to re-render needed elements.

Comment: Hahaha, I like how you think! I guess it's fine, but slightly more expensive for client (and possibly the server) than rendering a (prepared) partial. I don't see any security issue that you wouldn't have in a normal scenario.

Comment: @ClémentBaconnier is there really a big difference ? I will need to do the same work by fetching data so ... It may be expensive for a table because user will have to re render a lot of row but otherwise, it's like a user pressing F5 multiple times

Comment: It depends of the quantity you have to deal with. Let's say your request has 20 DB call that doesn't concern your fragment and 30k lines of HTML. The usage resource of your server + the time to construct the HTML + the request time + the parsing in your client side may not worth it. But if the number of DB call doesn't really change and your page has not that much content, I guess it's ok.